# Earth engine: function "is not defined in this scope"

Tags: area, google-earth-engine

I am trying to use in Google Earth Engine the function `area()` or `centroid()` on a simple polygon. According to the documentation, there seems to exist a method `area()` for objects *ee.Geometry.Polygon*. However, I get an error message with this simple code:

```js
var polygon = ee.Geometry.Polygon([
  [[-5, 40], [65, 40], [65, 60], [-5, 60], [-5, 60]]
]);

var a = area(polygon);
var aa = polygon.area();
```

Gives message:

> "area" is not defined in this scope.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `var a = area(polygon);` is probably what is giving the error.  Remove it.  The remainder of the code looks valid according to https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/geometry_visualization_info

Comment: Should the last coordinate be a repeat of the first coordinate? I see it's right from the doc. However, on [this page](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/features), the last coordinate is a repeat of the first coordinate.

Comment: Thanks @kttii , you are right! Happy to accept your solution if you post it. I am not sure in general why functionobject) does not work, and one needs object.function()? I thought these were interchangeable? As a coutnerexampl, one should use ee.Feature(object), not object.ee.Feature() ... what's the rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var a = area(polygon);` is what is giving the error. Remove it because it is not a valid function in this context.

The remainder of the code looks valid according to http://developers.google.com/earth-engine/geometry_visualization_in‌​fo